# CSS styles not working on Bootstrap-modal-leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, leaflet

I have imported in my project the leaflet-bootstrapmodal.js, however it looks as if I cannot style it, see plugins below:

```
        <!-- Bootstrap modal-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-modal/bootstrap-modal/leaflet-bootstrapmodal.css">
        <!--My plugin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="globeBig.png" class="logo"/>
        <h1 class="title">The Gazetteer</h1> 
        <ul class="list">
            <!-- Button trigger modal 
            <li>
              <button type="button" id="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" disabled>
                Show weather forecast for:
              </button> 
            </li> -->
            <li class="selector">
                <select class="country">
                    <option class="optionResult">Select a country</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav> 
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Modal weather -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal info -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="Info" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title" id="infoModalLabel"></h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-info">
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

Additional html.....






In style.css:

/* not workng below:*/
.modal-content{
    background-color: red;
}
```

I do not understand why by adding classes on my HTML I cannot customize the modal as there is the same class name applied and I do believe my styles plugin has to be after the modal package being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `!important` rule in CSS is used to add more importance to a property/value than normal.

In fact, if you use the `!important` rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element! - more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp).

```
.modal-content {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```